# median confusion to use key or value python

Tags: python

This is very basic. If I have the following:

```
{key  :  value}
'age20' = 10
'age21' = 10
'age22' = 12
'age23' = 12
'age24' = 40
```

Do we use the median as the key? So this would be `'age22'` or do we use the value? So its `'age23'`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value. Median is a value which in your case is 12.  If we use python set as analogy, I believe it is better to use the first occurrence  as the key, which is ‘age22’.

But frankly your question is too broad, and the objective is obscure, the best practice is never to assume. The python zen: Explicit is better than implicit, should be referred.